# different padding or line-height for two texts beside each other using CSS

Tags: html, css, padding

I want to get a desired `padding` or `line-height` for two types of texts which are beside each other using CSS. The problem is that, both texts are getting the style relatively and move together. I could come over the problem using `float` styling. But, I don't want to use `float` option here and I want to see if there's another solution for this type of issue.

```
<div class="somediv">
    <h1 class="header">Header</h1>
    <span class="entry">Text</span>
</div>

.header {
    font: 400 20px Tahoma;
    line-height:1; 
    /*padding: 10px 0; or even using padding */
}
.entry {
    font: 400 20px Arial;
    line-height:2; 
    /*padding: 20px 0; or even using padding */
}
```

Comment: Could you specify, that you'd like to achieve more transparently? Was span be intended to be the same size as h1?

Comment: They have of course using different types of fonts which I could not include here and they have to be at the same size. So, I have to achive this using a `line-height` or `padding` of course!!!

Comment: did you fix your problem?

Comment: not even using my answer?

Comment: I did, but did not helped me. Because one the fonts that I could not include here, was an icon font.